# double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000020f6e70 ***

Tags: c++

Я абсолютно не могу понять , почему почти два идентичных кода, но в первом из них выдает ошибку double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000020f6e70 ***, а во втором нет (написано на С++)

1 код:

```
    class Solution {
    public:
    void nextPermutation(vector<int>& nums) {
        int n = nums.size();

        int i = n - 1;
        while(i > 0 && nums[i] < nums[i - 1]){
            i--;
        }

        if(i == 0){
            reverse(nums.begin(), nums.end());
            return;
        }
        --i;
        int j = n - 1;
        while(j >= 0 && nums[j] <= nums[i]){
            --j;
        }


        swap(nums[i], nums[j]);
        reverse(nums.begin() + i + 1, nums.end());


    }
};
```

2 код:

```
    class Solution {
public:
    void nextPermutation(vector<int>& nums) {
        int n = nums.size();

        int i = n - 2;
        while (i >= 0 && nums[i + 1] <= nums[i]) {
            i--;
        }

        if(i == -1){
            for(int i = 0; i < (int)(n / 2) ; ++i){
                swap(nums[i], nums[n - 1 - i]);
            }
            return;
        }
        int j = n - 1;
        while(j >= 0 && nums[j] <= nums[i]){
            --j;
        }
        swap(nums[i], nums[j]);
        reverse(nums.begin() + i + 1, nums.end());

    }
};
```

В чем разница? Объясните, пожалуйста

Comment: Следует привести входные данные, на котором это происходит. И указать строку, на которой происходит падение. А то до минимального пример не дотягивает. На вид у вас индексирование может вылезать за пределы массива. Добавьте проверку индексов на валидность или используйте `vector::at` вместо оператора `[]`.

Comment: Если вы хотели "два идентичных кода", то почему в первом цикле строгость сравнения  поменялась? Было `<`, а стало вдруг `<=`. Вы сдвинули индексацию по `i` на единицу. Но никаких причин менять строгость сравнения значений я не вижу.

Comment: 1 код валится на тесте 1, 3, 2